# Reading from different samplers in an OpenGL Compute Shader results in odd pixelation

Tags: opengl, compute-shader

When using an OpenGL 4.5 compute shader, sampling from different textures based on a variable in the following manner results in odd pixelation. (first texture is red and second texture is blue)

```
#version 450

uniform sampler2D textures[2];

layout (binding = 0, rgba32f) uniform image2D framebuffer;

layout (local_size_x = 32, local_size_y = 32) in;

void main() {
    ivec2 pix = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
    ivec2 size = imageSize(framebuffer);
    if (pix.x >= size.x || pix.y >= size.y) {
        return;
    }
    vec2 tex_coords = vec2(pix)/size;

    int index;
    vec4 col;
    if (tex_coords.x > tex_coords.y) {
        index = 0;
    } else {
        index = 1;
    }

    /* This works */
    // for (int i=0; i<=index; i++)
    //     if (i==index)
    //         col = textureLod(textures[index], vec2(0,0), 0);

    /* These don't */
    col = textureLod(textures[index], vec2(0,0), 0);
    // col = texelFetch(textures[index], ivec2(0,0), 0);

    imageStore(framebuffer, pix, col);
}
```

[image]

Oddly enough, offsetting when the samples for different textures happens using a while loop seems to fix the problem. Using a workgroup size of 1 also seems to fix it. Anyone know why this behavior is happening and/or have a less hacky way of preventing it?

The full MRE for the code can be found at https://github.com/Luminic/TextureSamplingIssues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you get is well within the spec. THe GLSL spec states:

> Texture-combined sampler types are opaque types, declared and behaving as described above for
> opaque types. **When aggregated into arrays within a shader, they can only be indexed with a
> dynamically uniform integral expression, otherwise results are undefined.**

You can't really do that, and the workaround with the loop still is undefined behavior (although it is more likely to work by the way current GPUs work). A correct workaround would be:

```
vec4 texSamples[2];
texSamples[0]=texture(textures[0],...);
texSamples[1]=texture(textures[1],...);
col = texSamples[index];
```

However, you may be able to use *array textures* instead, where you can select the layer via arbitrary non-uniform expressions.